# Android 13 playing video by using VLC Player is not working?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, vlc

I wonder why on previous Android versions playing URL on VLC works well but on Android 13 not.Here is my working code:

```
int vlcRequestCode = 42;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(myreceivedLink);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc");
i.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "video/*");
i.putExtra("title", title);
i.putExtra("from_start", false);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.videolan.vlc","org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"));
startActivityForResult(i, vlcRequestCode);
```

And Error message is:

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.videolan.vlc/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
```

There is no special implementation in build.graddle.Something was changed in Android 13, do you have any suggestion how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks, help is to remove line with component:    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.videolan.vlc","org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"));.
Then it works as usual on Android 13.Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using Stanley to look at activities, it seems that the video player activity has disappeared. We might need to wait for a VLC update to make the activity visible again in 13.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).